# Stream data from AWS IoT to AWS Lambda using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am Publishing data from Raspberry Pi to AWS IoT and I can see the updates there. 
Now, I need to get that data into AWS Lambda and connect it to AWS SNS to send a message above a threshold. I know about working with SNS and IoT.
I just want to know that how I can get the data from AWS IoT to AWS Lambda ?? 
Please Help !!
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you search on AWS there is a lot of valuable information there, e.g. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-lambda-rule.html

Comment: Yes, I have been searching through Internet for past 3 days, tried a lot of different things but couldn't get it working. The AWS guide gives examples using the IOT Button for ehich they hve everything already setup. I am using RPi, so its like from scratch.

Comment: If you're looking to alert at thresholds and send to SNS queues when they are hit, I would look for a way to write your IoT data to cloudwatch as a custom metric, then create your alarms and notify an SNS queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IoT Code, **Create a rule** for invoking a Lambda to accept JSON data. Then you can do anything with that data.